# Why algebraic dual space of $V$ is denoted by $(V^*)^{ \otimes n}$?

Tags: tensor-products, dual-spaces

Why algebraic dual space of $V$ is denoted by $(V^*)^{ \otimes n}$, why not simply by $V^*$ ?, $n=\text{dim} \ V$.

What is the need of tensor product here and what does mean it?

Comment: Where did you see this notation being used?

Comment: @asdq, From this link-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set. See section $\text{Definition for vector space}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be careful with content from Wikipedia, some of the articles contain mistakes.

In the present case, $V^\ast$ is the algebraic dual space and $(V^\ast)^{\otimes n}$ denotes the $n$-fold tensor power. What the author of the article means is that $f_1\otimes\cdots\otimes f_n$ is an element of $(V^\ast)^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: Is it $(V^*)^{\otimes n}=V^* \otimes V^* \otimes \cdots \otimes V^*$ ? (n-times)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what is meant by this notation.